# Problem About Reading Turkish Character in char Array

Tags: c#, turkish

I have problem about my code,I thing C# doesn't read Turkish letters.

Here's my code;

```
        Console.WriteLine("Lütfen metin giriniz ve ardından 'ENTER' tuşuna basınız.");
        string Text = Console.ReadLine();//Klavyeden metin giriyoruz.

        char[] chr = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'ç', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'ğ', 'h', 'ı', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l','m','n',
        'o','ö','p','r','s','ş','t','u','ü','v','y','z','q','w','x'};

        int[] chrCount = new int[chr.Length];

        Text = Text.ToLower();

        for (int i = 0; i < Text.Length; i++) {
            for (int j=0;j<Text.Length;j++) {
                if (Text[i]==chr[j]) {         
                chrCount[j]++;
                                     }
                                            }
                                              }


        for (int i = 0; i < chr.Length; i++) {
            if (chrCount[i] > 0) {
                Console.WriteLine(chr[i]+" "+chrCount[i]);
```

When I type "tahsin başar paksoy", it doesn't shows letters after "ş".

How can I solve this problem?

With my regards.

Comment: You need to use Windows Encoding 1254 : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1254

Answer (score 1):

You need to set [Console.OutputEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.outputencoding?view=netframework-4.8) and [Console.InputEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.inputencoding?view=netframework-4.8).

By default, consoles use your system's default code page. It looks like your system's default code page doesn't support Turkish characters.

You can set it to UTF-8, to support all Unicode characters:

```
Console.OutputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
Console.InputEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
```

Comment: @tbpaksoy Could you please post your updated code, and post the actual, exact output of your application?